# Remove enclosing square brackets in an awk string

Tags: awk

How can I remove enclosing square brackets in an awk string?

For instance, I would have a variable `dgt` with value `[[:digit:]]` and want to remove the outer enclosing square brackets.

Currently my solution is very naive.

```
retval = substr(dgt, 2, length(dgt)-2)
```

Comment: what have you already tried?

Comment: Please show use sample input & expected output in a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example.](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: are you on `bash` shell?

Comment: I am on awk .....

Comment: *`outer enclosing square brackets`* sounds (to me) like you only want this operation to be performed *if* the string actually has two (or more?) brackets on the end, eg, while you would modify `[[:digit:]]`, you would ***not*** modify `[:digit:]` ... yes? or do you ***always*** want to remove leading/trailing square brackets regardless of how many there are?

Comment: @Roger, why need to apply awk for such a primitive variable cutting?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using `gsub` where `^` is the beginning of the string and `$` the end.

```
% awk 'BEGIN{str = "[[:digit:]]"; gsub(/^\[|\]$/, "", str); print str}'
[:digit:]
```